# Do Steam's global achievement stats sample from users who have launched the game or from all owners?

Tags: steam, achievements

Are Steam's global achievement statistics out of all owners or only those who have launched the game? The latter would make more sense, but [Universe Sandbox has an achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/UniverseSandbox/achievements/) awarded upon first starting the game and this, at the time of posting, is only owned by 90.9% of players. While this may seem like it answers my question, it's very possible some other funky stuff may happen with Steam not counting it for users.

**Is there any official source or concrete evidence that states what the global achievement statistics are counted out of?**

Comment: "Start Universe Sandbox at least once" could mean actually going into the game rather than starting it up, Hyperdimention Neptunia and Hyperdimention Neptunia Mk.II have an achievement which you gain from starting the actual game rather than starting it up. the achievement is achieved even before you see the first scene (Blanc/White Heart calling Vert/Green Heart Thunder Tits) as in both games when i wanted to make sure my DLC worked i started a new game and while i was going though all the messages i got the achievement, some games may wait till you start actual gameplay

Comment: I think this can't be answered, unless we have an official word from someone who works at Valve.  We can make, at best, estimates and guesses, but nothing concrete to support anything.  Voting to close.

Comment: That this question can not be answered is not true @thinlyveiledquestionmark, somebody could go away and source and official stance from somewhere. Kinda what he asked for in **bold**. Admittedly the answer could however be "No".

Comment: If there's currently no answer, but one appears in the future while this is closed, people won't be able to post the answer. I don't see any benefit to closing it. And the close reason that's being voted on really doesn't fit this. This has to do with Steam, not game development.

Comment: *This includes speculative questions about developer intent* This is the relevant part of the close reason, the only people who can answer you for certain are the people who can access the code. All we can do is speculate if it does or does not count people who never installed the game. (and that universe sandbox achievement is given on launching the game IIRC, so it'll be people who installed the game or people who own the game, and not people who launched the game.)

Comment: I'd suggest searching for people that had problems with that achievement unlocking.  With nearly 10% of users not getting it, I'd imagine there should be several discussions about it.  Otherwise, it is probably based on game owners.

Comment: @D3L Someone can always make inferences, but unless we have word from Valve or a dev there, there is nothing "concrete" enough to be true or false.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark That's my point, A reference if it exists _would_ be concrete enough, there is no need for a Steam dev to turn up to answer this. The internet is full of answers, some even official ;) just have to source them (source, valve, steam, hah, pun time). I think locking this question is over zealous, but this discussion is becoming meta now, so let's let it slide.

Comment: @D3L That is why Arqade is not a news site.  The expertise required to find this information is not a part of our skillset.  It falls into the category of "Dev design" questions, which are off-topic for that exact reason.

Comment: I humbly disagree with your opinion, this is supposed to be a knowledge based site. It is an on topic, gaming related question, focusing around the gaming service steam.

Some voters just don't the answer. Voting to close when you don't know the answer is a claim to ignorance, other people may know, or may come along. No one is asking _you_ to go investigate.

If what you require is a 'steam dev' to comment for the answer to be valid, then police the answers not the question.

Comment: @D3L The strawman you're arguing against doesn't help your case.  Questions that require knowledge from developers in order to answer are off-topic, irregardless of whether or not they're answerable.  There's a ton of discussion about it on Meta; I suggest you read that before criticizing our policies.

Comment: i'd _love_ to get an answer to that question (irregardless this being on or off topic over here)